# Page's side ScrollBar overlays page content

Tags: html, css

Asked 19 hours ago in CSS by Marcelo Miranda (20 points).
I'm trying to build an image gallery and I want the slide buttons to be on the extreme edges of the page.
the problem is that the right button gets overlayed by the page's scrollbar.
[image: Image gallery]

Is there any way to prevent that? I've tried to use this but it makes no difference at all.

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the complete code of what you are trying to build, otherwise we can't really provide any useful answers

Comment: Assuming that the arrows are positioned absolute, you can use `right:17px;` instead of `right:0` on the arrow element. This is the exact width of the scrollbar. Further suggestions cannot be done without any of your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent scrollbars from overlapping the content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439553/how-to-prevent-scrollbars-from-overlapping-the-content)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried making the scrollbar smaller?

```css
.long-content {
  height: 120vh;
  font-size: 128px;
}

/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 3px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1; 
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555; 
}
```

```html
<div class="long-content">Really Long Content</div>
```